# Internal 500 error ever time post or get Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post, get

Every time I try to post or use get from my file index.php which calls Ajax_mysql.php through the Ajax function POST or GET I keep getting a Internal 500 error. The server isnt giving any other error than that. I have included my javascript function that calls the serverside php.

```
function submit_login() {
    if( document.form.loggedIn.checked ) return
    request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.onreadystatechange = respond_login
    request.open("POST", "Ajax_mysql.php", true)
    request.send( "action=login&password=" + postEscape( document.form.pwd.value ) +
                    "&username=" + postEscape( document.form.user.value ))
    document.form.pwd.value = ""
    document.form.user.value = ""
}
```

Php Ajax_mysql.php:

```
<?php
$password_test = "fcb";
$username_test = "ben";
$action = $_POST['action'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
//Testing against hardcoded username and password
if ($username != $username_test)
{
 //output the response
 $response = "failed"
 echo $response;
}
?>
```

Comment: Forgot to comment out `Testing against hardcoded username and password`

Comment: There's a typo too - `$responce` vs `$response`.

Comment: In your real server code is the 'Testing against hardcoded username and password' line actually commented?

Comment: Turn on error reporting in php.ini

Comment: No that is commented out on the server code

Comment: Why not look into your http service error logs?

Comment: This might be a silly question but how do I turn on php.ini error reporting? I am using linux but am loggin in remotely from windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $responce = "failed"   //miss ;
echo $response;       // typo $responce;
```